# jQuery working awry

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have been using ajax to save a row.To do so i am showing edit icon on mouseover of the row and then saving it using ajax and then replacing the rows with newly formed row.
Problem is that it doesnt shows edit icon on the row again which has just been saved.

I dont know whats happening

Url is http://203.100.79.84:9733/user/login
U:test@test.com
P:test123
then move over to http://172.24.0.9:9733/application/events/13

and mouse over the grid rows try editing the record twice and you will see the problem.
Here is the code

```
jQuery('[rel="datepicker"]').datepicker();
          jQuery('[rel="innerRows"]').mouseover(function (){
          //alert('hererere');
            var spanId = jQuery(this).attr('spanid');
            jQuery('[rel="innerSpans"]').hide();
            jQuery('#edit_'+spanId).show();
          });
          jQuery('[rel="editButton"]').click(function (){
            var recordId = jQuery(this).attr('id');
            jQuery('#show_'+recordId).hide();
            jQuery('#hid_'+recordId).show();
          });
          jQuery('[rel="saveRecord"]').click(function (){
            var recordId = jQuery(this).attr('recId');
            var event    = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#event_'+recordId).val());
            var date     = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#date_'+recordId).val());
            var location = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#location_'+recordId).val());
            var notes    = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#notes_'+recordId).val());
            if(event !='' && date !='' && location !='' && notes !=''){
              jQuery.ajax({
                  url:'/application/saveevent/',
                  dataType: 'html',
                  data: '&recId='+recordId+'&event='+event+'&date='+date+'&location='+location+'&notes='+notes,
                  success : function (text){
                    jQuery('#hid_'+recordId).replaceWith(text);
                    bind();
                  } 
              });
            }



function bind(){    
          jQuery('[rel="datepicker"]').datepicker();
          jQuery('[rel="innerRows"]').mouseover(function (){
            var spanId = jQuery(this).attr('spanid');
            jQuery('[rel="innerSpans"]').hide();            
            jQuery('#edit_'+spanId).show(); 
          });
          jQuery('[rel="editButton"]').click(function (){
            var recordId = jQuery(this).attr('id');
            jQuery('#show_'+recordId).hide();
            jQuery('#hid_'+recordId).show();
          });
          jQuery('[rel="saveRecord"]').click(function (){
            var recordId = jQuery(this).attr('recId');
            var event    = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#event_'+recordId).val());
            var date     = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#date_'+recordId).val());
            var location = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#location_'+recordId).val());
            var notes    = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#notes_'+recordId).val());
            if(event !='' && date !='' && location !='' && notes !=''){
              jQuery.ajax({
                  url:'/application/saveevent/',
                  data: '&recId='+recordId+'&event='+event+'&date='+date+'&location='+location+'&notes='+notes,
                  success : function (text){
                    jQuery('#hid_'+recordId).replaceWith(text);
                    bind();
                  } 
              });
            }

          });          
        }
```

Regards
Himanshu Sharma.

Comment: Please put the relevant part of the code here in the post, so future visitors can see the problem and the answer even after the site has changed or gone offline.

Comment: you should use `$` instead of `jQuery`. also, read about the `.on()` event so you won't need to rebind stuff all over again.

Comment: @Joseph you can't tell him to use `$` without first knowing he hasn't reserved `$` for something else - he could have given it to prototype or another framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a future proof event observer. Either `on` or `delegate`. You are binding the hover event to all rows that are in the DOM, but when you add a new row, it has not been bound to that event.

You need to bind the event to the parent container, like so:

```
$('#myTable').on('hover','tr',function(){
    // show icon
});
```

Comment: Do you see the bind function called on ajax success it contains the whole mouseover events and all again so shouldnt it bind the new row?

Comment: You can't just call `bind()` and expect it to know what event it needs to bind to which node :)

Comment: I just added the bind function there @Alien.Please have a look

Comment: That's both redundant and inefficient. Trust me, you want to use `on` here.

Comment: I mean will it work on the newly injected rows into the dom also?

Comment: Just replace `jQuery('[rel="innerRows"]').mouseover(function (){` with `jQuery('#myTable').on('mouseover', '[rel="innerRows"]', function (){`. Do that for all the events you need future-proof. No need to re-bind inside the `success` callback.

Comment: Guy There is textbox inside that table which has to show datepicker.I was bounding it like this jQuery('[rel="datepicker"]').datepicker but now as per your suggestion i did it jQuery('.tableClass [rel="datepicker"]').datepicker but it does not work on the textboxes which are inserted into DOM after ajax call.

Comment: That's not an event binding issue, it's a plugin invoking issue. The plugin looses scope to the field you want. Re-invoke it in the success callback.

Comment: so what i can do here?I tried invoking the plugin on ID of each textbox using onclick,but it didnt helped too.

Comment: Also will using ON bind the newly inserted elements as well?

Comment: If i use jQuery('body input[type=text],textarea') wont it bind the newly inserted HTML?